# Computation of an integral containing d ln x (Scale of Market Shocks)

Tags: numerical-methods

I am trying to implement a Scale of Market Shocks method (SMS) which was presented in a 1999 working document by Olsen & Associates named [Introducing a Scale of Market Shocks](https://web.archive.org/web/20000819023632/http://www.olsen.ch:80/research/workingpapers/322_SMS.pdf) and later refined in a paper named [Measuring Shock in Financial Markets](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/263868774_Measuring_Shocks_in_Financial_Markets). SMS is based on [Operators on Inhomogeneous Time Series](https://web.archive.org/web/20010205003900/http://www.olsen.ch/research/workingpapers/324_operators_2.pdf).

Now, I was able to figure out everything except for the main part, that is defined in [the latter document](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/263868774_Measuring_Shocks_in_Financial_Markets) on page 3 as:

$$S(t) = \gamma\int d~\text{ln}~\tau~~\mu(\text{ln}~\tau)~~\nu[\tau](t)$$

Here, $\tau$ is a time horizon, for which the price volatility $\nu$ is measured. And $\mu$ is just a smoothing function.

The thing I am not able to comprehend is $d~\text{ln}~\tau$. With $dx$, I would use a numerical method, such as [scipy.integrate.romb](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.romb.html), to approximate the value, but here, I have no idea of how to write a code for this kind of integration.

Furthermore, the authors mention this pattern again when discussing the smoothing function, which is defined as:

$$\mu(\text{ln}~\tau) = c~e^{-x}\left(1 + x + {x^2 \over 2}\right)\text{, where}~~~x = \left|\alpha~\text{ln}\left({\tau \over \tau_{center}}\right)\right|$$

They say: *“The constant $c$ is adjusted so that $\mu$ is a unit measure $\int d~\text{ln}~\tau~~\mu(\text{ln}~\tau) = 1$.”* I do not even understand what that sentence means, let alone how to transform such a remark to a working code.

So my questions are: how can I calculate the before-mentioned integral for $S(t)$? And how to use that knowledge in order to obtain a value of the constant $c$?

Comment: Informally, you can think of the integral sign as similar to a "loop" in a programming language. The symbol dt inside the loop says you increment t by a small amount $\epsilon$ in each iteration. The symbol "d ln t" says you increment t by a small percentage in each iteration, for ex you multiply t by $(1+\epsilon)$ in each iteration. This gives a more efficient way to reach large values of t.

Comment: @AlexC I see. Now this statement from the paper makes sense to me: “Practically, the integral is computed with τ's ranging from 1 hour to 42 days, on a logarithmic grid with reason $2^{1 \over 4}$” So I just replace the integration with a loop and that's it.

Comment: OK. So apparently for the number I called $(1+\epsilon)$ they are using the value $\sqrt{\sqrt{2}}\approx 1.1892$. And it takes them about 40 iterations to go from 1 hour to 42 days. Assuming I didn't mess up the calculation...

Comment: Apparently some people call this Integration Over a Logarithmic Space https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/54650-integration-over-log-space

Comment: At last, I was able to compute SMS. I had been trying different methods and the result is that I chose the `scipy.integrate.trapz` function that was able to approximate the integral using logarithmic samples. Furthermore, fiddling with the $c$ constant, I ended with $c = 0.1$. Thanks @AlexC, I appreciate your helpfulness.